# Why does random number generator not show on html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a random number of customers to "have gone on the website today". Why does the number not show on the page. I am sorry if this is something obvious but I am very new.

```js
var customerNumber = document.getElementById("customer-number")
customerNumber.textcontent = randomCustomerNumber()

function randomCustomerNumber(){
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36)
    return(i)
}
```

```html
<div class="customers-today">
    <h4>You are customer number <span id="customer-number"></span> today.</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.textcontent` => `element.textContent`

Also you should prob change `return(i)` to `return i;`, both work but the first one makes it seem like return is a function.

Comment: Using "return i" instead of "return(i)" is only for readability, there would be no other difference?

Comment: Yea, no difference. But still recommended

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `textContent` instead of `textcontent` :

```js
var customerNumber = document.getElementById("customer-number")
customerNumber.textContent = randomCustomerNumber()

function randomCustomerNumber(){
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36)
    return(i)
}
```

```html
 <div class="customers-today">
  <h4>You are customer number <span id="customer-number"></span> today.</h4>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
var customerNumber = document.getElementById("customer-number");
customerNumber.innerHTML = randomCustomerNumber();

function randomCustomerNumber(){
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML`  is more security vunerable, and you aren't append real html to it so `textContent` is probably better practice.